# How to add a new page to IconButton on app bar in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I wanna a direct onTap of iconButton on the appbar to open a new page but navigator doesn't work.I tried FlatBitton.Icon on the app bar instead of icon button but its crashing the page.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.Post the code of what you have tried @Marc Walton.

Comment: Can you add some peace of your code in your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is an example:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: 'Navigation Basics',
    home: FirstRoute(),
  ));
}

class FirstRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('First Route'),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.add_box),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute()),
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text('First route'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Second Route"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          child: Text('Go back!'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```